# PRSice.R: error: Error in getopt(spec = spec, opt = args) : long flag "" is ambiguous

Tags: r, genetics

I'm using PRSice2, and this error kicked in with the R scripts. I downloaded the lasted OS X 64-bit v2.3.5. I also tried the v2.3.3. Both packages gave the same error.

**Here's my entire script:
PRSice_mac % Rscript PRSice.R 
-- prsice PRSice_mac 
-- base PGC3_SCZ_wave3_public_without_frequencies.clumped.v1.tsv 
-- target pncEA 
-- fastscore 
-- bar-levels 5e-8,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1 
-- no-regress 
-- out pncEA 
-- score std

**Here's the output:
Usage: PRSice.R [options]

PRSice.R: error: Error in getopt(spec = spec, opt = args) : long flag "" is ambiguous

Thanks for helping me out!

I tried re-install PRSice2 packages, both v2.3.3 and v2.3.5 for Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is an unnecessary space in the command lines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).